# Replace Null with "absent" in SQL Server in result after procedure execute statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to replace `null` with `absent` when statement is executed in stored procedure

This is the stored procedure:

```
create proc attendance
(
 @year varchar(100) = null  , 
 @month varchar(100) =null  , 
 @centerId   varchar(100)     =  null
)
as
begin
   declare @day  int
   set @day = 2

   declare @days varchar(8000)
   set @days = '[1]'

   WHILE (@day <= 31)
   BEGIN
       set @days = @days + ',[' + convert(varchar, @day) + ']'
       set @day  = @day + 1
       --print @days   
   END
   --print @day 

   DECLARE @query varchar(8000)  //** Here If the condition don't match it gives NULL but I want to print absent instead of NULL **//
   set @query = 'SELECT TB05001,' + @days  + 'from 
     (SELECT TB05001, TB05003, day(TB05002) as day FROM TB05, tb04 
           Where  tb04023 =' + @centerId + ' and  year(TB05002)=' + @year + '  and month(TB05002) =' + @month + 'and tb04003=tb05001            
         ) AS SourceTable 

       pivot ( 
            MAX(TB05003)
               for day in (' + @days +')
             )p'

 print('pivoted report')    
exec(@query)
end
```

When I enter the data

```
exec attendance '2013', '11', '1004'
```

This is the return output and I want to replace null with absent

[image]

Comment: Can you not use IsNull,  `IsNull(FieldName, 'Absent') As FieldName  `

Comment: please give the full code , how to use this with dynamic sql statement and pivot keyword is also there

Comment: Is the plan to adjust this stored procedure later to produce a variable number of columns based on the number of days in the month? Because if not, I don't see why you're using dynamic SQL at all - the entire query shape stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
create proc attendance
(
 @year varchar(100) = null  , 
 @month varchar(100) =null  , 
 @centerId   varchar(100)     =  null
)
as
begin
   declare @day  int
   set @day = 2

   declare @days varchar(8000)
   set @days = '[1]'
   -- Declare final column names for Pivot 
   Declare @columnsday NVARCHAR(MAX)
   set @columnsday = 'isnull([1],''Absent'') as [1]'
   WHILE (@day <= 31)
   BEGIN
       set @days = @days + ',[' + convert(varchar, @day) + ']'
       set @columnsday = @columnsday + ',ISNULL ([' + convert(varchar, @day) + '],''Absent'') as '+ convert(varchar, @day)
       set @day  = @day + 1
       --print @days   
   END
   print @days 
   print @columnsday


   DECLARE @query varchar(8000)  //** Here If the condition don't match it gives NULL but I want to print absent instead of NULL **//
   set @query = 'SELECT TB05001,' + @columnsday  + 'from 
     (SELECT TB05001, TB05003, day(TB05002) as day FROM TB05, tb04 
           Where  tb04023 =' + @centerId + ' and  year(TB05002)=' + @year + '  and month(TB05002) =' + @month + 'and tb04003=tb05001            
         ) AS SourceTable 

       pivot ( 
            MAX(TB05003)
               for day in (' + @days +')
             )p'

print('pivoted report')    
exec(@query)
end
```

[Edit]: Three corrections done:
     1. Space added before from keyword
     2. Quotename function added 
     3. As [1]..[31] are of datetime datatype in Pivot List.. and 'Absent' is varchar 
        explicit conversion is required.

```
alter proc attendance
(
 @year varchar(100) = null  , 
 @month varchar(100) =null  , 
 @centerId   varchar(100)     =  null
)
as
begin
   declare @day  int
   set @day = 2

   declare @days varchar(8000)
   set @days = '[1]'
   -- Declare final column names for Pivot 
   Declare @columnsday NVARCHAR(MAX)
   set @columnsday = 'isnull(cast([1] as varchar(10)),''Absent'') as [1]'
   WHILE (@day <= 31)
   BEGIN
       set @days = @days + ', ' + quotename(convert(varchar, @day)) 
       set @columnsday = @columnsday + ',ISNULL(cast(' + quotename(convert(varchar, @day)) + ' as varchar(10)) ,''Absent'') as '+ quotename(convert(varchar, @day))
       set @day  = @day + 1
       --print @days   
   END
   --print @days 
   --print @columnsday

   DECLARE @query varchar(8000)  
   set @query = 'SELECT TB05001,' + @columnsday  + ' from 
     (SELECT TB05001, TB05003, day(TB05002) as day FROM TB05, tb04 
           Where  tb04023 =' + @centerId + ' and  year(TB05002)=' + @year + '  and month(TB05002) =' + @month + 'and tb04003=tb05001            
         ) AS SourceTable 

       pivot ( 
            MAX(TB05003)
               for day in (' + @days +')
             )p'

print('pivoted report')    
exec(@query)
end

go
```

Comment: this is the error i got
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: this is how I execute the procedure and I get above error
exec attendance '2013', '11', '1004'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create proc attendance
(
@year varchar(100) = null  , 
@month varchar(100) =null  , 
@centerId   varchar(100)     =  null
)
as
begin
   declare @day  int
   set @day = 2

   declare @selectdays VARCHAR(Max)
   declare @pivotdays VARCHAR(Max)

   SET @pivotdays = '[1]'
   set @selectdays = 'IsNull([1], ''Absent'') As [1]'
   WHILE (@day <= 31)
   BEGIN
       SET @selectdays = @selectdays + ',IsNull([' + convert(varchar, @day) + '], ''Absent'') As ' + Convert(Varchar, @day) 
   SET @pivotdays = @pivotdays+ ',[' + CONVERT(varchar, @day) + ']'
   set @day  = @day + 1

   END       --print @day 

   DECLARE @query varchar(max) 

   SELECT @query = 'SELECT TB05001,' + @selectdays  + 'from (SELECT TB05001, TB05003, day(TB05002) as day FROM TB05, tb04 
       Where  tb04023 =' + @centerId + ' and  year(TB05002)=' + @year + '  and month(TB05002) =' + @month + 'and tb04003=tb05001            
 ) AS SourceTable 

   pivot ( 
    MAX(TB05003)
       for day in (' + @pivotdays +')
     )p'
 print('pivoted report')    
exec(@query)
end
```

Comment: i think column alias in pivot column list statement won't work that is statement: for day in (' + @days +').

Comment: this is the error i got
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: this is how I execute the procedure and I get above error
exec attendance '2013', '11', '1004'

Answer (score 0):

```
ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
```

[here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT Statement That Returns the values from PIVOT just USE following function

```
SELECT ISNULL(Column, 'Absent')
```

And Use NVARCHAR(MAX) variable to build Dynamic SQL Query.

Comment: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE

```
Case when ' +@days+' is null then ''absent'' else '+@days+' end as '+@days
```